# name 'request/self' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Getting requests is not defined. please find the below code(I'm not using it directly in CBV).

**views.py**

```
 class ShiftChangeUpdateView(request,PermissionRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
        permission_required = ('apple.change_shiftchange',)
        model=ShiftChange
        logger.info('Data has been Deleted by  %s !', request.user.username)
        fields='__all__'
```

I have checked by using self also but no luck.
**urls.py**

```
   url(r'^updategenesys/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ShiftChangeUpdateView.as_view()),
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: A class-based view has *no* request at the class level... Remove the `request` (which is here seen as base-class), and override `form_valid` to do the logging.

Comment: A Python class body is parsed and executed when the containing module is imported (i.e. when your Django application starts up). As Willem said, there will not be a request at that time as the application has not even started, yet alone accepted a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use parameters like in a function, but that is not how a class is defined. You thus can not use `request` as a base class.

What you can do is override `form_valid`, and perform logging in that method when the form is successful:

```
#                  no request ↓
class ShiftChangeUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = ('apple.change_shiftchange',)
    model=ShiftChange
    fields='__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        logger.info('Data has been Deleted by  %s !', self.request.user.username)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class you don’t inherit request